# How to insert any nested json object to elasticsearh by using JAVA API

Tags: java, elasticsearch

In my project, we use flink to handle log data, then we send the data into elastisearch. However, I find that es could not recognize json object, it only recogize some basic data types. Therefore, I could only transform json object into a string, but in this time, when I check log data in elasticsearch, the format is really hard to understand.

```
"hits" : {
"total" : 10,
"max_score" : 1.0,
"hits" : [
  {
    "_index" : "wyh_dye_test",
    "_type" : "nested",
    "_id" : "gzlvM3EBRgA6CE7yDw8l",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "id" : "id",
      "module" : "wyh_key",
      "content" : """{"map":{"wyh_key":"wyh_value","user_key":"user_value","wqq_key":"wqq_value","hello_key":"hello_value"}}"""
    }
  }
```

this is my kibana search result, as you can see, the content field is really hard to read.

Comment: can you share your elastic index mapping ?

Answer (score 0):

You can update this index mapping,then put the data into the corresponding field.

```
PUT xxx_index/_mapping/xxx_type
{
"properties": {
    "wyh_key": {
        "type": "keyword"
    },
    "user_key": {
        "type": "keyword"
    },
    "wqq_key": {
        "type": "keyword"
    },
    "hello_key": {
        "type": "keyword"
    }
  }
}
```